# Nests on Banach spaces and their duals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, duality

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\mathcal{E}$ a nest on $X$.
Take $f\in X^{*}$ and suppose:

- $N \in\mathcal{E}$ is the largest element of the nest so that $f \in N^\bot$
- $N=\bigcap_{M>N}M$

Is there a function $h \in M^{\bot}$ for some $M>N$  so that for all $\epsilon >0$, $\|f-h\|<\epsilon$ ?

I have been thinking about this for a while, but I have not found a proof of the existence of such $h$.

Does anyone know an example of a Banach space and a nest were there is no such $h$?

Comment: I assume you mean "for every $\epsilon >0$ there is an $M>N$ and $h\in M^\perp$..."

Comment: Anyway, discrete nests will easily provide a counterexample. Or did you mean something different by "nest"?

Comment: Yes, I do mean for every $\epsilon >  0$, sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you , Nik. :)